# proper CSS for generating a checkmark li that works cross-browser

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I'm using the following CSS to add checkmarks before my `<li>`list items:

```
ul.checkmark li:before {
    content:"\2713\0020";
}
```

And then in the HTML:

```
<ul class="checkmark">
   <li>Learn the keyboard at your own pace</li>
</ul>
```

Works great in Safari, Firefox and Chrome, but displays "freak out boxes" on IE8.

Safari:
[image]

IE8:[image]

Is there a portable way to specify a good-looking checkmark that will work in all the major browsers?

**EDIT Solution**:
I ended up using a variation on meder's answer below:

```
ul.checkmark li {
    background:url("../checkmark.gif") no-repeat 0 50%;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

ul.checkmark {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Instead of background position `0 50%` you might want to use pixels instead of positioning the checkmark in the center (50%), otherwise it will be centered also when you have multiple lines in list item.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
li { background:url(/images/checkmark.gif) no-repeat 0 50%; }
```

Would probably be the only way you'll get it to work consistently in the IE pre 8/9.

Comment: I have used this technique a lot and it is fine in IE.

Answer (score 5):

```
ul
{
    list-style-image:url("/default_unchecked.png");
    /* other list styles*/
 }
```

then later change it via javascript, maybe.

```
$('.selected').css("list-style-image", "url('/images/blueball.gif')");
```

Comment: Just came across your answer on Google. The javascript part of your answer is not necessary. The question is only asking how to replace bullets with checkmarks in a `<ul>` list. It doesn't mention anything about adding a `selected` style. I +1ed it anyways since you are the only one who mentioned using `list-style-image`

Comment: @KodosJohnson You might be right here. At the time, that was the only way I knew of changing default state to a "checked" state. Let me see if I can make the answer better. Thanks.

Comment: Using a background image with the contents of the li in a span is still the superior method due to the flexibility that a background image allows. A list style image bullet is impossible to adjust and often times will not be in the desired spot next to  your text.

Answer (score 4):

Hmmm how about going with a small image instead, then you'll get full compatibility with practically every browser

Alternatively take a look at this past question [Tick symbol in HTML/XHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658044/tick-symbol-in-html-xhtml)

Comment: Please find an article on making this solution backwards compatible here: https://css-tricks.com/put-checkmarks-next-to-visted-links-with-pure-css/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if anyone still needs to support IE8 but I wanted to find out why IE8 creates those boxes so I searched the internet and found this post: [Unicode characters and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027448/unicode-characters-and-internet-explorer)

So based on the answers to that question, it looks like you *can* use the method described by the OP, you just have to specify a Unicode font to make IE8 happy. So in theory this should work fine:

```css
ul.checkmark {
    list-style-type:none;
}
ul.checkmark li:before {
    content:"\2713\0020";
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Arial Unicode MS', Arial;
}
```

```html
<ul class="checkmark">
    <li>Learn the keyboard at your own pace</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an old post but, with the many variations of screen sizes and pixel densities on mobile devices, I think the best approach is to convert your icon into a font with a program like Icomoon: https://icomoon.io/

Put the font files on your server and the css will look something like this.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'IcoMoon-Free';
    src: url('/fonts/IcoMoon-Free.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.icon {
    /* use !important to prevent issues with browser extensions that change fonts */
    font-family: 'IcoMoon-Free' !important;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;

    /* Enable Ligatures ================ */
    letter-spacing: 0;
    -webkit-font-feature-settings: "liga";
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga=1";
    -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga";
    -ms-font-feature-settings: "liga" 1;
    -o-font-feature-settings: "liga";
    font-feature-settings: "liga";

    /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-checkmark:before {
    content: "\ea10";
}
```

The html will be something like this:

```
<span class="icon icon-checkmark"></span>
```