# IE6 bad displaying unicode: &#9768;

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6

I have strange problem in IE6: When I'm trying to display "cross of lorraine" - I actually get something like empty rectangle, it's bad displayed in ie6. How can I workaround this problem? Cross of lorraine: ☨

I don't like workaround with displaying image with it for IE6 only

Ok I've actually found: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027448/unicode-characters-and-ie) - but for cross of lorraine (☨) does not working

source file: 
index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
</head>
<body>
&#9768;
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add this little script to your website: http://code.google.com/p/ie6-upgrade-warning/

Comment: @Willem you just saved me a lot of time implementing one of my own :)

Comment: @smas, Can you provide example code? Specifically I'd like to see the doctype and encoding for your page, and the markup surrounding the character.  Also, what fontset is your page using?

Comment: @KatieK I've attached, but it's nothing special

Comment: I am fairly sure this is a font issue. Does this work in other browsers on the same system?

Comment: it works correctly in other browsers - only IE6 has the problem. I think similar that this is font problem and I was searching font which support this in IE6 (I tried Arial Unicode MS) but still don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6 cannot display all of the Unicode characters available.  IE6 cannot display that one.

I've tried quite a few different encodings and fonts, all to no avail.  Even [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_of_Lorraine) cannot make IE6 display that character.

You will need to use a workaround such as an image or substitute character for IE6.