# Display image with css content

Tags: html, css

I have to work on a symphony project written by others. I've investigated why some icons, like facebook icon or shopping cart icon won't display on IExplorer, when I found something I dont understand: The html and css below outputs a facebook icon and I don't know how?

HTML:

```
<i class="facebook-icon"></i>`
```

CSS:

```
.facebook-icon::before{
  content:"\e905";
}
```

What does this mean, how does this work?

Comment: Maybe its just doesn't really support IE. did you try it in other browsers?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Its because of the font file that is attached to it.. the content by itself is useless.

Comment: That is probably a unicode character. Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027448/unicode-characters-and-internet-explorer. You might have to specify a unicode font for IE like `font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial Unicode MS, Arial;`

Answer (score 2):

They are using a custom font in which the character \e905 is just a facebook icon

Comment: please dont use `maybe` while answering . Answer it after being sure, or comment

Comment: I'm just trying to help here. There's no need to downvote me just because I used the word maybe