# Can I make any unicode symbol (i.e. "") work in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, unicode

I am considering using this neat [text arrow](http://graphemica.com/%F0%9F%A1%A8) () in a new website. It works well in Chrome and Firefox as expected. And, of course, not at all in Internet Explorer. Not even in Edge...

Can I make it work in IE as well?

---

- I already tried using the arrow as it is or as HTML entity `&#129128;` instead
- I am already using `<meta charset="utf-8">`

---

### Update

The solution presented in [Unicode characters and Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027448/unicode-characters-and-internet-explorer) does not work for this character, as this demo shows:

```html
<p style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS;">&#9398;</p> <!-- works in IE -->
<p style="font-family: Arial Unicode MS;">&#129128;</p> <!-- does not :( -->
```

This is how it looks in IE (Edge):

[image]

Comment: you could try telling your clients to get out of 2008

Comment: for real though, try researching before you ask since i've found something here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027448/unicode-characters-and-internet-explorer

Comment: FWIW, macOS doesn't know this character yet either in any default font…

Comment: I'm using the latest Firefox on Windows and `U+1F868` is not showing up, even when using Unicode fonts like Lucida Sans Unicode and Arial Unicode MS. So, you are best off just using an image instead of a Unicode character.

Comment: @L_Church To be fair using Edge is a legit attempt to get out of 2008.

Comment: didnt even see the edge mention thats how useless it is... jokes i legit didnt read that bit and im silly

Answer (score 1):

Not the very same character, but the best alternative (using an arrow to the right, and rotating it 180°).

```html
<span style="display:inline-block; transform: rotate(180deg);">➔</span>
```